# Split out a branch into a new repo

Tags: mercurial

I have a mercurial repo that now effectively contains two repos.
At some point in the past, a branch was split off from *default* (let's call it *default-other*).
Both *default* and *default-other* now have a lot of commits and there are no plans to ever merge *default-other* back to *default*. Some commits have been grafted from *default* to *default-other*.

Now, I want to create a new repo from the *default-other* branch while retaining the full history. i.e. a repo that contains

- all commits from *default* up to the point where the *default-other* branch was created
- all commits from *default-other*
- all branches that have been branched off from *default-other*
- no commits from *default* after *default-other* was branched off

Optimally, I would like to use different strategies for different branches. Some branches are release branches which must be kept, whereas others are feature branches which I would like to fold into the new *default*.

I tried using the convert extension, but I cannot figure out how to correctly set up the branch map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do almost everything you stated using `hg strip`. Something like this:

1. Clone the original repo to a new repo
2. `hg up null` to remove anything from the working directory (probably quicker to work with it like that)
3. Identify all branches (named or anonymous) and changesets that you want to remove. To be precise, what you want is the changeset ID of each commit and its descendants that should be removed.
4. `hg strip -r 12345678890` for each of those commits. This removes the commit & all its descendants (potentially including merges).

If needed, you can do this procedure twice, but the second time strip the orthogonal set of changesets (those which pertain to *default-other* but not to *default*).

That said, there are a few reasons you might still want to use `hg convert`:

1. There are files in the repo that are not relevant.  For instance, if *default* branch had some old stuff which has nothing to do with *default-other*. You could use `convert` to eradicate history of such files.
2. You want *default* and *default-other* to look like they were always the same branch. You can use `convert` to rename one or both of them. (`branchmap`)
3. You want to ensure the new repo(s) cannot be pushed/pulled with the original which could mess up all your well-laid plans. By "converting" the entire repo, IIRC all the changeset IDs will be renewed and the repo will not look like a relative of the original.

---

My advice would be to work in stages:

1. Clone the original to clone1
2. Use `strip` to get as much done as you can
3. Make clone2 from clone1
4. Run `convert` task #1
5. Make clone3 from clone2
6. Run `convert` task #2

etc.

I recommend not batching many different `convert` things together - run them in small increments. This may seem like it will take longer, but its much easier to get right this way.

Ultimately you can remove all the intermediate clones, but through experience I found this was the most productive & safest way to make big structural changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [described in wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--branchmap) format of branchmap. In your case it will be easy plain

```
default-other default
...
renamed-child1 default
renamed-child2 default
...
```

## Addition

Because Convert extension can't stop conversion of condition "before ", only "after " (see [`--rev`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--rev) option), you must to prepare repository for conversion before convert process (clone into new intermediate repo only subset or original changesets without `default`, only `default-other` and descendants?)

Comment: Thanks, but using this branchmap, I will get commits from default-other and default, but I want to "cut off" default at the point where default-other was branched off. Updated question to make this requirement clearer.